# How to analyze Sharepoint dataset size?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint 2007(wss 3) instance that is growing about 600 Mb a day. Is there a report or tool that will show me where this space is being used?

Answer (score 2):

The [MSIT reporting framework](http://msitsrf.codeplex.com/) has a site size tracking report.

Comment: Good catch on MSIT on Codeplex

Answer (score 0):

Used this evaluation at one point and it has some great reports.  [AdminReportsKit](http://www.softpedia.com/get/UNIX/Networking/Server-Applications/Admin-Report-Kit-for-SharePoint-2003.shtml)

Not sure if there is anything on [Codeplex](http://features.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2502)  Worth a look

Answer (score 0):

You can also get a handle on who's using the most space by library, document, list or recycle bin with "Storage Space Allocation" under Site Settings->Site Collection Administration. This comes with a catch, though: you have to enable a site collection quota in central admin before you can see it (Central Administration->Application Management->Site Collection Quotas and Locks).

We just enabled a sufficiently large quota using the "Individual Quota" template, and got to set a size warning as a bonus. It's certainly not as full-featured as the other stuff, but it's built in.